# Cannot resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

I'm trying to add Firebase support for my app

i added `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'`

to project level gradle file and added

```
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.6'
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

when i sync i get 
[image]

when i try to clean the project i get

```
    Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
```

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.6.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth/10.2.6/firebase-auth-10.2.6.pom
>            file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth/10.2.6/firebase-auth-10.2.6.jar
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth/10.2.6/firebase-auth-10.2.6.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth/10.2.6/firebase-auth-10.2.6.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/Adi/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth/10.2.6/firebase-auth-10.2.6.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/Adi/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth/10.2.6/firebase-auth-10.2.6.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/Adi/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth/10.2.6/firebase-auth-10.2.6.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/Adi/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth/10.2.6/firebase-auth-10.2.6.jar
>   Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/10.2.6/firebase-core-10.2.6.pom
>            file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/10.2.6/firebase-core-10.2.6.jar
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/10.2.6/firebase-core-10.2.6.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/10.2.6/firebase-core-10.2.6.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/Adi/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/10.2.6/firebase-core-10.2.6.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/Adi/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/10.2.6/firebase-core-10.2.6.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/Adi/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/10.2.6/firebase-core-10.2.6.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/Adi/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/10.2.6/firebase-core-10.2.6.jar
>
> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.6.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth/10.2.6/firebase-auth-10.2.6.pom
>            file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth/10.2.6/firebase-auth-10.2.6.jar
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth/10.2.6/firebase-auth-10.2.6.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth/10.2.6/firebase-auth-10.2.6.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/Adi/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth/10.2.6/firebase-auth-10.2.6.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/Adi/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth/10.2.6/firebase-auth-10.2.6.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/Adi/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth/10.2.6/firebase-auth-10.2.6.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/Adi/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth/10.2.6/firebase-auth-10.2.6.jar

i have updated google play services to latest version and it's still not working.
i tried invalidate cache & restart..

how do i solve this?
thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android Studio, the "Google Play services" developer tools component version 40 will get you access to Firebase and Play dependencies version 10.2.6.  At this moment, there is now also version 41 that makes version 11.0.0 of the dependencies available.

Please [check your versions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and try again.

[image]

Comment: i have version 41 and it gives same "cannot resolve" error `Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.0`

Comment: I don't have any problems finding that at all.

Comment: Maybe also Google Repository?  Ideally you keep everything you need fully up to date.  Android Studio should tell if you anything is out of date.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and after updating the following my issue was resolved:

- Google Repository (revision: 53)
- Android SDK Platform-Tools (revision: 26.0.0)